# current analysis with pre-carried current in the inductor .- confused

Tags: circuit-analysis, inductor

[image]

[image]

The direction of the reference i(t) current is certain. When we add the pre-existing currents, it will be -12 amperes, thats okay. But why did we multiply it by - (minus) when we integrating the expression Voltage and multiply it by inductance (I marked it with a yellow marker)?

Comment: When we use the formula \$v(t) = L di(t)/dt\$. We would have marked the current arrow starting from + side of \$v(t)\$. In this circuit, that would have meant \$i_1\$ and \$i_2\$ being marked top to bottom. But the convention marked in the figure is bottom to top. This may be the reason for the additional -ve sign. You can compare to other problems you have worked out in the past to confirm this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a inductor is modelled as

\$v(t) = L \frac{d\ i(t)}{dt}\$,

the reference *polarity* of the current is an arrow pointing from +ve part of \$v(t)\$ to -ve part.

In the question, the current reference direction is marked in the *opposite* direction. Hence the equation for these inductors would be

\$v(t) = - L \frac{d\ i(t)}{dt}\$.

[image: inductor reference polarity]

Above image taken from [slide 24](https://www.ius.edu.ba/sites/default/files/u772/ee202laplacetransform.pdf) for a reference.

### Note

The fact that the current values are negative and the voltage values are negative (-1800V), do not affect how the equations are setup. The numerical values are substituted after setting up the equations. The negative sign appears while setting up the equations. Th screen shots do not show the details as two separate steps (writing equations in terms of symbols and *then* substituting values).

Comment: What I understand is this:
(I am accepting conventional flow., from + to -)
The actual flow direction is the same as the passive sign representation, ie the current is flowing from top to bottom. Passive sign according to the sign, above +, below -.

So, regardless of the sign of the voltage, I put it inside the integral expression (I write the voltage expression as it is).

However, since the reference current is inverted with my passive sign, I add a - (minus) sign to the beginning.

Did I get it right?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "*The actual flow direction is the same as the passive sign representation*" since in this very example the actual flow in both inductors is in opposite directions even though they are connected to voltage source in the same way.

But you are right in that the marked reference current direction is inverted w.r.t to the (passive?) convention. That makes a -ve sign required.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do (initial current) - (integral expression) because the current is running out.
I get it now